# spring-cloud: Error deploying two eureka clients in one container

Tags: spring-cloud

I have two services which are eureka clients (using @EnableDiscoveryClient). Both services are packaged in separate war files. At the time of deployment (single tomcat container), one service gets deployed but during the deployment of second service, below error is thrown

==============Log ===================================

```
[2015-01-28 19:11:01.030] boot - 6832 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] --- SpringApplication: Application startup failed
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentMana
ger@ca848c] with key 'environmentManager'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.envi
ronment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:613)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:538)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:782)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5185)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentMana
ger
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
        at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:666)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:603)
```

Comment: what does eureka show?

Comment: Which ever service Tomcat picks first, gets deployed and is visiible in eureka-server dashboard. Other service deployment fails and hence not registered with eureka-server. Have added more log statements above.

Comment: Looks like two `org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManager`'s are trying to be registered in jmx and there can only be one?

Comment: Yes...every war has one attached to it. Is there a way to override the key for environment manager so that it is unique for each war.

Comment: Not at the moment, can you create a github issue and reference this conversation?

Comment: Created..https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka/issues/8

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is a Spring Cloud question - it's just a feature of Spring Boot and JMX. You can set `spring.jmx.default-domain` to something different in each application or provide your own `ObjectNamingStrategy` or your own `@EnableMBeanExport` (with a unique `defaultDomain`).